# avm.sty-related errors in Overleaf v. 2

Tags: overleaf

I am using [a package called avm.sty](https://nlp.stanford.edu/manning/tex/avm.sty) for attribute-value matrices. After I moved a project to Overleaf v.2, I got errors in all of my AVMs, something complaining about the nested opening brackets (which should, of course, be completely fine, and they were fine in v.1).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{avm}
\begin{document} 
\begin{avm} 
\avml  
\[\textit{comp-lex-item}\\ 
HEAD & \[\textit{comp} \\ 
MOD & \q<\ \q>  \]\\ 
SUBJ & \q<\ \q>\\ 
COMPS &  \q<\ \avmbox{1} \[ HEAD & {\it verb} \\ SUBJ & \q<\ \q> \\ 
COMPS & \q<\ \q> \\  
HOOK & \avmbox{2} \] \q>\\  
ARG-ST & \q<\ \avmbox{1} \q>\\ 
RELS & \q<! !\q>\\ HOOK & \avmbox{2} \] 
\avmr  
\end{avm}
\end{document}
```

Here's what the error looks like:

[image]

And here's [a piece of the project exemplifying the problem](https://www.overleaf.com/5453985893nhrvtsxxqbff).

The red highlighting associated with the error starts at line 71. The document can be rendered just fine, the problem is only with the highlighting over the source. How to fix this?

Comment: Please, don't post code screenshots. Instead, make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document that shows the problem. But anyhow, you have a `\[` (on line 239) inside another `\[` (on line 238), which, in normal circumstances, can't be nested.

Comment: the link you give is not public.

Comment: For a public link, click on the "Share" button above the preview panel in your Overleaf project, and then "Turn on link-sharing". You can then copy and paste the read-only link, which doesn't require an Overleaf account to view.

Comment: Posted a public link.

Comment: opening brackets can be nested with avm.sty

Comment: Added a minimal working example.

Comment: `avm` is not a standard package, and it may be introducing non-standard notation. So, accommodation for that might not be top-priority.

Comment: It's just that there is that little backward compatibility problem...

Answer (score 1):

*(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)*

Overleaf v2 has a ["code check"](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check) function that tries to highlight syntax errors as you type, but there can be false positives as in this case. You can turn Code check off, by clicking on the Overleaf menu icon above the file list panel, and then set "Code check" to "off".

To disable code check for only part of the code, you may use the `%%begin novalidate` and `%%end novalidate` markers, like this:

```
%%begin novalidate
\[\textit{comp-lex-item}\\ 
...
RELS & \q<! !\q>\\ HOOK & \avmbox{2} \] 
%%end novalidate
```

You may need to refresh the page for the red markers to clear away, after adding those lines.

Comment: Thanks, this is great to know. So, basically this is Overleaf v.2 being unaware of avm.sty? Is there hope that this will be fixed? It is nice to be able to use the code check, generally :).

Comment: It's really just because the code check can't parse the, ah, exotic syntax with `\[` and `\]` in this case. It only knows `\[...\]` as a math construct, so is alarmed to see nested `\[...\]`.

Comment: Well, what I am saying is, this was confusing to me because it used to be supported in version 1. (And the ``exotic syntax'' is used within a specific environment here which is clearly defined in the imported package). Anyway, turning off the warnings is a practical workaround, thanks for letting me know how to do that!

Comment: I've added info on how to disable code check for only part of a file.